# identifying idle events in google Big Query.existing procedure

Tags: google-bigquery

How can we identify idle events in Google Big Query.
The events that have been pushed by a user but not being queried.
I need to know if there is any existing procedure that i can follow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking about query jobs that have been created but have not yet started running? If so, you can call jobs.list() and specify the PENDING state as a filter. Query jobs are generally only in the pending state for a very brief time however, unless you have specified batch priority.